# Convert Matlab matrix into video file

Tags: matlab, video-processing, yuv

How can I convert a matrix to a video file? Specifically in the yuv format. Or convert it to .avi first then going to yuv. Does anyone have codes for this? It was originally an .avi file then I extracted all the frames into an array or structure.

I found this on stack overflow and used it. I created a 4D structure in Matble [height width Y/U/V numberOfFrames]. I'm using qcif so it's size is [176 144 3 150] but the video created was erroneous. (all white) Should I convert it to RGB first?

```
Orig; % 3D matrix
X = permute(Orig,[1 2 4 3]); % 4D matrix
movie = immovie(X,map); % map is the colormap you want to use

implay(movie);
```

Also, in my program, the original YUV file was first converted to avi. So my structure of frames are from an avi file.

Comment: Have you looked at this yet: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriterclass.html ?

Comment: Yes, but it is not currently supported by my Matlab version.

Comment: So then http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/avifile.html ?

Comment: can i create an avi file from a matlab matrix?

Comment: ...yes you can, did you read the example in the second link? Use `avifile` and `addFrame`

Comment: how about directly going to yuv?

Comment: i really don't understand avifile. the input argument is the avi file you want to create. and the output is avi object right? How can I reference it from a matrix?

Comment: You use `addframe` to add slices of your matrix to it, like in their example. `avifile` creates the file and initialises the object, `addframe` gets the data (frame by frame) into the avi. Just loop through the 4th dimension (or 3rd if your image is indexed) and add each slice with `addframe`

Comment: @Dan can you please make a sample code using avifile to create an avi file that contains the frames of the matrix i have in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this:

```
aviobj = avifile('example.avi','compression','None');

for frame = 1:size(M, 4)
    aviobj = addframe(aviobj, M(:,:,:,frame); %// This is assuming your image is a vector of RGB images. If it's a vector of indexed images then drop one : and make the loop go to size(M,3)
end

aviobj = close(aviobj);
```